# Warnings for system.str

Tags: delphi

If you compile the following program with Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo

```
{$apptype console}
var
  spi: string;
begin
  str(pi:10:5, spi);
  writeln(spi);
end.
```

then you get the warning:

> `tst.pas(5) Warning: W1057 Implicit string cast from 'ShortString' to 'string'`

although `spi` is declared as string and the prototype of system.str also has a string (according to http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Str and the online help):

> `procedure Str(const X [: Width [:Decimals]]; var S: String);`

but the actual code with debug dcu calls this **function**:

> `function _Str2Ext(val: Extended; Width, Precision: Integer): _ShortStr;`

Obviously the compiler does some kind of magic here, but
is this a bug in the documentation or in compiler?

How can I get rid of this warning by coding (not by suppressing warnings),
the first try

`str(pi:10:5, ShortString(spi));`

will throw an error message:

> `tst.pas(5) Error: E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to`

Interestingly there is no *Left side*.

Comment: Tried everything. It doesn't seem you can get rid of the warning, unless you use a real ShortString or an AnsiString. That may not be posssible in the mobile compilers.

Comment: Vendor seems to have forgotten to deprecate intrinsics when it deprecated shortstrings.

Comment: There is a left side, as you are in fact calling `ShortString(spi) := System._Str2Ext(pi, 10, 5);`.

Comment: @Rudy I think you could have use RawByteString in your answer in order to be mobile compliant.

Comment: Do you really need to use `str`? It is ancient.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: See my comment to David's answer. Do you know a better way to get a string compatible with floating point literals? And of course the path over shortstring is an option, but IMO the documentation should be corrected.

Comment: @gammatester: You could, of course, use the modern alternatives (`Format`, `FloatToStr`, `FormatFloat`, etc.) with the format settings of your choice (give the function your own `TFormatSettings` record).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Delphi 2..6 do not even know `TFormatSettings`. As already said, I want a "portable" way, and str is promising it. The other functions work with DecimalSeparator and/or do not support the width:decimal format.

Comment: @gammatester: Cannot you solve that using conditional compilation? You could create your own portable "float to string" function that way.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I have already said, that there is no fundamental difficulty. I can use a function with an internal shortstring and do an explicit type cast (as shown by David's answer). The questions is whether the current implementation is a compiler or a documentation bug. That both disagree should be obvious.

Comment: @Sertac: correct. But only in the current versions, not in older ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is indeed doing some "*magic*" behind the scenes.

`STR` is a very old library routine. It's been around since the Turbo Pascal days.  When it was created, the only strings were `ShortString`s.  Of course, in those days, they were just called `string`s.

The routine does not use the standard syntax for calling procedures or functions in Delphi, and so the compiler does "magic" to convert it internally to a standard function call, and that function returns a `ShortString` as it always has. That result is then implicitly converted to a string, and that is triggering the warning.

In order to avoid the warning, you can call the routine with an actual `ShortString`, and then convert it explicitly to a `string`.

```
var
  aShortString : ShortString;
  aString      : string;
begin
  str ( pi:10:5, aShortString );
  aString := string(aShortString);
  writeln ( aString );
```

Or you could skip using `STR` altogether and use a more modern approach:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils;
var
  S : string;
begin
  S := Format ( '%10.5f', [ pi ] );
  writeln ( S );
```

The `STR` routine is still supported for backward compatibility. Personally, I use this routine in code I wrote in 1984 that is still a part of my modern Delphi application today.

Comment: This is nothing new, I know it. Any way, do you agree that the docs are wrong, should this
be reported to QC? The reason I use str is, that I want a "portable" function, that
does not use DecimalSeparator (do get the char for DecimalSeparator I need at least
three different routines, dependent on the compiler version), but thank you for the answer. +1

Comment: Hard to know what you mean by portable, but you certainly don't need to be using short strings these days.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: "Portable" = the same procedure/function for all Delphi version (3 .. Tokyo). I do no really want shortstrings but the str seems to want it,  contary to the documentation.

Comment: If you want to work with so many different versions, then you can't expect things to be clean and simple. You are writing library code I guess. But really, who uses Delphi 3?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, I am using the D3 and D6 IDEs (and Tokyo, other console programs support even BP7 for 16-bit systems). I do not really expect a uniform coding for all versions. But it should be as simple as possible, and str would do this according to the docs. (As already said I need three functions to get the DecimalSeparator char. I guess there is a good reason, why the Pascal literals always are written with '.')

Comment: I know where you're coming from.  When I'm in a hurry I'll resort to using STR and VAL to write code that does not depend on locale information.  How many hours have I spent trying to convince my colleagues that you can't always reverse FloatToStr by using StrToFloat.

Comment: Regarding whether to notify QC, they are certainly aware of the issue, and the page you linked to says: " Notes: However, on using this procedure, the compiler may issue a warning: W1057 Implicit string cast from '%s' to '%s'  "

Comment: Thank you David, I should have read until the bottom. But since I was familiar with val and str I only looked at the prototype. So it seems the question is almost answered.

Comment: @DavidDubois I'm not aware of any Pascal code that can successfully convert between float and string, and vice versa.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You can say that there is no code in any programming language that could sucsessfully convert float to string and then back so that the final floating value is always the same as it was in the beginning. The reason for this is that when you are converting float to text you are also doing coversion from binary to decimal numerical system. And since it is imposible to store any binary number in decimal numerical system or vice versa some rounding occurs during coversion process. This then causes the final result to differ from the original.

Comment: @SilverWarior *"You can say that there is no code in any programming language that could successfully convert float to string and then back so that the final floating value is always the same as it was in the beginning"*. What you claim is categorically not true. There do exist functions that do this (e.g. David Gay's `dtoa`). I'm not aware of any written in Pascal.

Comment: My FloatToString/StringToFloat comment was just meant to point out that since it uses locale, the former might use "." as decimal point, while the second might be expecting "," if run on a different machine.  This took me several hours to track down the first time it happened to me.  Whereas STR/VAL always use ".", it is not an issue.

Comment: FYI, I have routines written in Pascal that will convert any single, double or extended value to its exact decimal representation and back again.  Example, the built-in value pi:extended becomes:  3.14159265358979323851280895940618620443274267017841339111328125